# List DynamoDB tables works with aws cli but not using boto3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm trying to retrieve all dynamodb tables with boto3. Using AWS CLI with:
`aws dynamodb list-tables`
It works:

```
{
  "TableNames": [
    "table_name1",   
    "table_name2",
    ...
}
```

But with boto3, It does not retrieve them. If I test another service with boto3 like S3 to retrieve buckets, it works. So it is not a connection/rights problem.

Here's my simple code:

```
import boto3

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "xxx"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "xxx"
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN = "xxx"
AWS_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-1'

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_session_token=AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
    region_name=AWS_REGION_NAME
)
available_services = session.get_available_services()
print("Available services:")
print(available_services)

s3_client = session.client('s3')
print("===== S3 =====")

buckets = [bucket['Name'] for bucket in s3_client.list_buckets()['Buckets']]
print(f"Buckets {len(buckets)}")

dynamodb_client = session.client('dynamodb')
print("===== DynamoDB =====")
table_names = dynamodb_client.list_tables()['TableNames']
print(f"Tables {len(table_names)}")
print(table_names)
```

And the output

```
Available services:
['accessanalyzer', 'account', ...'dynamodb'...'s3'...]
===== S3 =====
Buckets 150
===== DynamoDB =====
Tables 2
['LimitMonitor-SummaryDDB-1951SZYTWET87', 'LimitMonitor-SummaryDDB-FEBN4S1LC0OF']
```

So with aws cli, it lists more than my hundred tables, with boto3, only 2: `LimitMonitor-...`, I don't know what they are.

Is something wrong using boto3 dynamodb client?

Comment: Try using a Paginator so it will keep pulling pages automatically for you. I’m on a phone so I can’t easily send sample code.

Comment: In fact, the problem was due to bad aws region

Comment: Cool, if your table list grows long enough you’ll need a Paginator still. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad problem solved.
It concerns AWS_REGION_NAME which was set to 'us-east-1' instead of 'eu-central-1'. I can see buckets as it's global.